# Updating CSS in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, caching

I am working in Wordpress and I have custom css files that are part of my theme. These files are working fine, but after a week I went back to edit the CSS in them and the updates aren't rendering to the page.

In my inspector tool, I noticed the file is books.css/ver=6.3.2 and I feel like that is what I need to update. I tried clearing my cache, going incognito, etc and haven't found a solution. After Chat GPTing, I added a random version calculator at in the fuction.php file, so now the call looks like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'books', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/books.css', array(), rand(111, 9999));
```

This works but I am curious why and how and if there is another solution that doesn't seem as odd.

Comment: what cache did you clear? it could be the cache of a wordpress by some plugin

Answer (score 0):

If we take a closer look at the Wordpress docs of **wp_enqueue_style** (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/), the 4th argument is **$ver**.

By default if you omit it, ***it will default to your WP version i.e 6.3.2***. Many Wordpress and hosting caching solutions as well as local browser caches use the ver of CSS and JS files to ***determine whether the file should be requested again aka clear the cached version***.

If you don't want this file cached you can do any of the following:

- exclude the CSS file from your Wordpress caching plugin
- exclude the CSS file from your hosting caching solution

**However I would not recommend any of the above.** The good practice is to update the ver everytime you change the file and it should be requested again:

```
if ( ! defined( '_S_VERSION' ) ) {
    // Replace the version number of the theme on each release.
    define( '_S_VERSION', '1.0.0' );
}

function my_scripts() {
    // CSS Files
    wp_enqueue_style( 'books', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/books.css', array(), _S_VERSION );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts', 200 );
```